# Swift - Stop avaudioplayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am trying to build a soundboard into an app and have figured out an efficient way of using tags to control playing the sounds. However I am now trying to integrate a pause button that can be used with the `.stop()` method on the `AVAudioPlayer` however I get an error with my current code:

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

This is what I am using at the moment, any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

let soundFilenames = ["sound","sound2","sound3"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

     var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     for sound in soundFilenames {
          do {
               let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound, ofType: "mp3")!)
               let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
               audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
          } catch {
               //Catch error thrown
               audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
          }
     }
     }


     @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
          let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
          audioPlayer.play()
     }
     @IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {
          audioPlayer.stop()
     }

}
```

Comment: that does work...but only for the first sound file that is played i.e. the one with the same tag as the stop button. I would like the stop button to stop all sounds no matter what their tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your audioPlayer in stop function is not the playing player. You should assign it in buttonPressed function.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
      audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
      audioPlayer.play()
 }
```

By the way, You can mark audioPlayer as a "?" property, it will be more efficient when init this Controller.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

     var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

     let enableMuiltPlayers = false
....


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
          if sender.tag < audioPlayers.count else {
               print("out of range")
               return
          }
          if enableMuiltPlayers {
             audioPlayers[sender.tag].play()
          } else {
             audioPlayer?.stop()
             //set the current playing player
             audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
             audioPlayer?.play()
          }
     }

     @IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {
          let wantToStopAll = false
          if enableMuiltPlayers  && wantToStopAll {
              stopAll()
          } else {
              audioPlayer?.stop()
          }
          audioPlayer = nil
     }
}
```

to stop all:

```
fun stopAll() {
    for player in audioPlayers {
        player.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Should i call the stopAll from the stop function?

Comment: If you play the audios in the same time, you should call stopAll function if you want to stop all of them.

Comment: Thank you very much - Working perfectly now after calling the stopAll function

Answer (score 2):

Your code may have other faults, but there's one thing sure:

**You should not instantiate `AVAudioPlayer` using default initializer `AVAudioPlayer()`.**

Change this line:

```
     var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

to:

```
     var playingAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
```

And change this part:

```
          } catch {
               //Catch error thrown
               audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
          }
```

to something like this:

```
          } catch {
               //Catch error thrown
               fatalError("Sound resource: \(sound) could not be found")
          }
```

---

(The latter part is very important to solve the issue. But I found it had become just a duplicate of some part of Hao's answer after I edited it...)

And `start` method:

```
     @IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
          let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
          audioPlayer.start()
          playingAudioPlayer = audioPlayer
     }
```

And `stop` should be:

```
     @IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
          playingAudioPlayer?.stop()
     }
```

Comment: This almost works but if two files are being played at the same time, only the original one that was tapped stops.

Comment: @dwinnbrown , correct. Main concern of this answer is focused on "you should not use `AVAudioPlayer()`" to avoid this sort of errors. I believe Hao's `stopAll()` will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
if audioPlayer != nil {
    if audioPlayer.playing {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some information on why and how this solves the problem described by OP