# How to make a button in Xcode that globally stops AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to make a tableviewcell stop all sounds in the app when it is clicked. I know how to stop sounds with `soundEffect.stop() soundEffect.currentTime = 0`, but I don't know how to apply this to a cell and this doesn't work if the StopSound button is on another viewController with a different class. How do I make a function that globally stops AVAudioPlayer and apply that to a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the player is not alone. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409834/swift-stop-avaudioplayer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

To stop AVAudioPlayer on another ViewController you may use NotificationCenter.

Example...

First time, add function at VC, where you need to stop AVAudioPlayer.

```
@objc func stopAVonThisVC() {
    AVaudioPlayer.stop()
}
```

Second, add NotificationCenter observer at this VC, and after just post on tap button.

```
    // At VC, where you need to stop AVAudioPlayer.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
    #selector(stopAVonThisVC), name: NSNotification.Name("Stop at VC1"), object: nil)
    // At VC2
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Stop at VC1"), object: nil)
```

Sorry for poor english.

Comment: Wow, notification center is great. This worked for me so well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BaseViewController` for your project and subclass all your view controllers from there,

Define the `AVAudioPlayer` in BaseViewController and invoke `soundEffect.stop() soundEffect.currentTime = 0` from any of your subclass, it should resolve the issue.

Example:

```
    class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPayer: AVAudioPlayer!
     }


    class ViewControllerA: BaseViewController { 
    //start or stop audio player
    }

    class ViewControllerB: BaseViewController {
    //start or stop audio player
    }
```

Comment: This is a useful idea, I didn't know about subclassing. I'm gonna test if this works with UIViewController and TableViewController together.